# Is it possible to make PhantomJS visible in Watir-WebDriver?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

I know it's possible to use phantomJS with Watir-Webdriver, but is there some 'mode' I can pass it to actually see what it's doing before I decide to use the (default) headless mode?

Comment: There is no other mode for phantomjs except headless. You might need to use some other browser: chrome, firefox, slimerjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could log all the request and responses using [onResourceRequested](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) and [onResourceReceived](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) api's. I do this for a scraper I wrote in [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) which uses phantomjs underneath. The  Watir-Webdriver should provide some hook into webPage object of phantomjs.

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
  console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(requestData));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response));
};
```

Comment: There's no such hook unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about a mode, but you can try this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
b.screenshot.save 'step1.png'
b.goto "www.google.com"
b.screenshot.save 'step2.png'
b.url #"http://www.google.com/"
b.screenshot.save 'step3.png'
b.title #"Google"
b.screenshot.save 'step4.png'
```

You'll get output that looks like this:
[image: screenshot of step 2]

Answer (score 2):

Extending other responses, you can automatically do screenshots before clicking or sending keys to element.

```ruby
class Screenshotter < Selenium::WebDriver::Support::AbstractEventListener
  def before_click(_, driver)
    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot-#{Time.now.to_i}.png")
  end

  def before_change_value_of(_, driver)
    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot-#{Time.now.to_i}.png")
  end
end

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs, listener: Screenshotter.new)
```

Moving forward, you can join all screenshots to a GIF which will work like live video of your test.

Answer (score 1):

Like artjom B is writing, there is not possibility for other modes than headless in PhantomJS.

So either change the browser - I have made all my tests able to run in every browser by changing an Environment variable in the CMD box.

Or else take a lot of screenshots with:
@b.screenshot.save 'filename' - and you can follow the flow through even though you keep on using PhantomJS